# Pin Annotations not being dropped at CloudKit CLLocations

Tags: ios, swift, function, cloudkit, cllocation

I want pins to appear on the map with their annotations at the locations that are stored in cloudkit. The records are being saved and queried but nothing appears on the screen. When you originally make an event it appears on the screen until the app restarts.

```
@IBAction func makeEvent(sender: UIButton)
    {
        var title2 = String()
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Event?", message: "Please name your event:", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: .Default) { (_) in
            if let field = alertController.textFields![0] as? UITextField {
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(field.text, forKey: "userEvent")
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
                let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.loc1.coordinate.latitude, longitude: self.loc1.coordinate.longitude)
                let lat: CLLocationDegrees = center.latitude
                let long: CLLocationDegrees = center.longitude
                self.pointAnnotation1 = MKPointAnnotation()
                self.pointAnnotation1.title = (field.text)
                title2 = field.text!
                self.pointAnnotation1.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
                self.pinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: self.pointAnnotation1, reuseIdentifier: nil)
                self.mapView?.centerCoordinate = self.pointAnnotation1.coordinate
                self.mapView.addAnnotation(self.pinAnnotationView.annotation!)
                let center1 = CLLocation(latitude: self.loc1.coordinate.latitude, longitude: self.loc1.coordinate.longitude)
                self.eventRecord.setObject(center1, forKey: "event")
                let publicData = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
                publicData.saveRecord(self.eventRecord) { record, error in
                }
                if self.error == nil
                {
                    print("Event saved")
                }
                } else {
            }
            self.titleRecord.setObject(title2, forKey: "titles")
            let publicData1 = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
            publicData1.saveRecord(self.titleRecord) { record, error in
            }
            if self.error == nil
            {
                print("Title saved")
            }
        }

func drawEvents(loc: CLLocation, title1: String)
    {
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: loc.coordinate.latitude, longitude: loc.coordinate.longitude)
        let lat: CLLocationDegrees = center.latitude
        let long: CLLocationDegrees = center.longitude
        self.pointAnnotation1 = MKPointAnnotation()
        self.pointAnnotation1.title = title1
        self.pointAnnotation1.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
        self.pinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: self.pointAnnotation1, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        self.mapView?.centerCoordinate = self.pointAnnotation1.coordinate
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(self.pinAnnotationView.annotation!)
    }

func loadEvent(completion: (error:NSError?, records:[CKRecord]?) -> Void)
    {
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Event", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true))
        CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil){
            (records, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("error fetching events: \(error)")
                completion(error: error, records: nil)
            } else {
                //print("found events: \(records)")
                print("found events")
                completion(error: nil, records: records)
                guard let records = records else {
                    return
                }
                let query1 = CKQuery(recordType: "Title", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true))
                CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase.performQuery(query1, inZoneWithID: nil){
                    (records1, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        print("error fetching titles: \(error)")
                        completion(error: error, records: nil)
                    } else {
                        //print("found event title: \(records1)")
                        print("found event title")
                        completion(error: nil, records: records1)
                        guard let records1 = records1 else {
                            return
                        }
                        //for record in records
                        for(var i = 0; i<records.count; i += 1)
                        {
                            for(var j = i; j<i+1; j += 1)
                            {
                                self.drawEvents(records[i]["event"] as! CLLocation, title1: records1[i]["titles"] as! String)
                                print("drawing events")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The code you posted does not include whatever code you use to retrieve the records from CloudKit. Please edit your code snippet to include that code. Also when/where are `self.titleRecord` and `self.eventRecord` initialized? Are you making a new CKRecord for each pin? (which is almost certainly what you want to do)

Comment: yes I am. they are initialized at the top of my class. i added the loading code. Thanks. @breakingobstacles

Comment: So what is the output of your current code? You have several `print` statements sprinkled throughout - what does it print?

Comment: Also, if the "Title" and the "Event" are related, they should be in the same CKRecord. You cannot guarantee the order of the records CloudKit returns to you. Right now, you are *relying* on the order that CloudKit returns the Events and Titles.

Comment: Ill have to check output later, but yes they are related. @breakingobstacles

Comment: also how can I access the separate parts of a record. I thought they could only hold one piece of data

Comment: Please review the [CKRecord documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/cloudkit/ckrecord) (or open a new question with that specific question). Also, `saveRecord` executes asynchronously - your code that handles the results needs to be **in** the completionHandler block.